# Pros/cons of higher profile tires?

Tags: tires

I have a 2002 Hyundai Elantra, which ordinarily comes with P195/60R15 87H tires. What are the pros and cons of changing these tires to a set of P185/65R15 86T? Some sites say they're compatible, but not all do, and while I understand the benefits of [*lower* profile](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/846/what-are-the-benefits-of-low-profile-tires) tires, there's not much talk on higher profile ones.

Comment: Not very on topic, so I post as comment: In general compatible sizes pros is that certain sizes are more common/cheaper than others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caveat: all of the following information is heavily dependent on the tire construction, tread pattern, application, etc.  If you care more about a particular application, you should research that specifically:

A higher profile tire will potentially affect the following factors:

1. Comfort: increased - you've increased the vertical air space in the tire, allowing the tire to adapt to small bumps pneumatically before they hit the suspension.
2. Handling: decreased - a taller, less stiff sidewall will generally reduce turn-in ability and responsiveness (i.e., in back-to-back comparison, you'll notice a distinct lag between turning the wheel and seeing the car turn).
3. Deep snow performance: increased - a tall thin tire is better able to dig down into a deep pile of snow than a wider shorter tire.
4. Speedometer reading: different - the rolling circumference between the two tires will almost certainly be different.

Regarding that last point: there are plenty of rolling circumference calculators on the web.  I plugged your numbers into [this one](http://www.club80-90syncro.co.uk/Syncro_website/TechnicalPages/TRC%20calculator.htm) and it thinks that the difference at the highest level would be 20 millimeters of circumference.  The calculator estimates that there would be a difference of about 1 kph (i.e., too small for most people to observe on a standard speedometer).

Now, considering your specific example, [Tire Rack](http://www.tirerack.com/snow/WinterPackageMain.jsp?autoMake=Hyundai&autoModel=Elantra%20GLS%20Sedan&autoYear=2002&autoModClar=) does list both of these sizes as valid choices for winter tires.  Its [default search](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/SelectTireSize.jsp?autoMake=Hyundai&autoModel=Elantra%20GLS%20Sedan&autoYear=2002&autoModClar=) does not show that size but that may be more of an assessment of their customer base than a judgment.

Using all of the above, if this was my vehicle where I live (i.e., I buy all-weather tires since deep snow is rare), I would not go with a taller tire.  There are plenty of tire vendors, brands and applications available for me to select a stock size tire without sacrificing our mutual criteria (comfort for her and handling for me).

Comment: @MarkJohnson, in the US, it's almost certainly illegal to do anything that might affect the odometer (so updating the computer to show a different number is off limits).  1 KPH is in the realm of errors that can be introduced due to under/over inflation or tire wear (i.e., not really a cause for concern).

Comment: Thanks @BobCross! I've decided it's worthwhile to stick with the original-size tires. Like you, I don't deal with much snow, and while I "only" drive an Elantra, I do appreciate good handling. :-)